# How to sensibly split an array around an object

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of uncertain length, let's say `[1,2,3,4,5]`. I want to subtract `1` from everything before `3`, and add `1` to everything after `3`, making the example `[0,1,3,5,6]`. If there is no `3`, add `1` to everything: `[1,2,4,5]` => `[2,3,5,6]`. What is the most graceful way of doing this?

Comment: My friend did it using indexes, and I did it with a combination of take_while and reverse.drop_while. Both of those felt clumsy and wasn't readable.

Comment: Is the array always sorted?

Comment: I realise I did not specify this but the array is in the order I want it split in. Even if it was `[10,1,3,20,30]`, I would want it `[9,0,3,21,31]`.
The original idea for the question came from an array of strings where we were doing different operations before and after a certain string. I used numbers in this example for convenience.

Comment: this is clunky to provide a functional solution for because the operation changes depending on if 3 is in the array or not.  It would be far cleaner if the spec were to *subtract* 1 from everything if 3 were not in the array.

Comment: @roippi I sort-of understand what you mean, but that is also a biased view. It depends on from which side you scan the array. If from the left, then subtracting 1 until it hits `3` means subtracting 1 from all when there is no `3`. But if you scan from the right, then adding 1 to all would be natural.

Comment: @sawa yes, I quickly realized you could just scan from the end, see my answer I just posted.  It does still add a couple of reverse operations, which does still fit my "clunky" test, ymmv :)

Comment: @roippi I saw your answer, and realized we came at the same conclusion regarding this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = a.index(3) || -1
a.map.with_index{|e, i| e + (i <=> n)}
# => [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]
```

Comment: `a = [1,2,4,5]`
`#=> [1, 3, 5, 6]`
Doesn't increment the one in the second case.

Comment: @BookOfGreg I realized that. I just fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit on the question by the way. Think this is the best so far but still uses indexes. There has got to be a more functional way of doing this.

Comment: I can think of a way without indice, but I think it is less pretty.

Comment: Beautiful solution! +1

Comment: @BookOfGreg If you want to go along the way you suggested in a comment to Andrew Marshall's answer, then `slice_before` can be a hint, but I think it will be uglier.

Answer (score 1):

So in order to get this on *strictly one* pass through the array, you need to start at the end, adding one to each element until you hit 3, then start subtracting one.

```
arr.reverse_each.slice_before(3).flat_map.with_index do |ar,i|
  ar.map do |x|  
    x += 1 if i == 0 unless x == 3    
    x -= 1 if i == 1    
    x
  end  
end.reverse
```

You could write the inner block a lot more concisely but I like it explicit since this code is hard enough to read as-is.

I don't think this really buys you anything in terms of readability or performance, but it sure is *functional*!  (seriously, use @sawa's answer, it is beautiful)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this **(Supposing that the array is sorted)**

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
n = 3
a.include?(n) ? a.map {|e| e < n ? e-1 : e > n ? e + 1 : e } : a.map {|e| e + 1} 
# => [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]
```

That was one-line sintax, if you prefer that way...

```
if a.include?(n)  
   a.map {|e| e < n ? e - 1 : e > n ? e + 1 : e }
else
   a.map {|e| e + 1}
end
```

Comment: Most imaginative abuse of ternary I've seen lately and correct, but not very readable.

Comment: It operates correctly for both of my specified cases. It is technically correct.

Comment: @BookOfGreg Does it work correctly for your `[10,1,3,20,30]` example?

Comment: No, but I did not specify that in my original question, it would be unfair to test these answers against that requirement.

Comment: @BookOfGreg In the text, you clearly described using `before` and `after`; you did not say `smaller` or `larger`. That was clear enough, although the examples were a bit not clear. Adding a stipulation that they are sorted is a clear departure from what was asked.

Comment: @Sawa: we agree that your solution is better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
if your_array.include?(3)    
  your_array.map do |item|
    if item > 3
      item + 1
    elsif item < 3
      item -1
    else
      item
    end
  end
else
  your_array.map{ |item| item + 1 }
end
```

Comment: This answer it does not cover the second condition that PO says.

Comment: right, I agree with the previous answer. We need an include? check first

Answer (score 0):

```
def doit(a)
  n = a.include?(3) ? -1 : 1
  a.map { |i| (i==3 && n == -1) ? (n = 1; i) : i + n }
end

doit([1,2,3,4,5]) #=> [0, 1, 3, 5, 6] 
doit([6,5,4,2,1]) #=> [7, 6, 5, 3, 2]
doit([1,2,3,4,3]) #=> [0, 1, 3, 5, 4]
```

I add one to every three after the first, but if they are to be left unchanged, that's an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do as below :

```
def add_sub(a)
  ind = a.index(3)|| -1
  a.each_index.map do |i|
    if ind < i
      a[i] + 1
    elsif ind > i
      a[i] - 1
    else
      a[i]
    end
  end
end

a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a2 = [1, 2, 7, 4, 5]

add_sub(a1) # => [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]
add_sub(a2) # => [2, 3, 8, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @sawa's answer

If you want to manually go through the array, here's a straight-forward way to do it:

```
def trans_around(arr, elmt)
  ret = []

  found_at = -1 

  for i in 0...(arr.length) 
    if arr[i] == elmt
      found_at = i 
      break
    else
      ret << (arr[i] - 1)
    end
  end

  if (found_at > -1)
    ret << arr[found_at]

    for i in (found_at + 1)...(arr.length)
      ret << (arr[i] + 1)
    end
  else
    # rectify all the -1's we've done
    ret.each_with_index { |e,i| ret[i] += 2 }
  end

  return ret
end
```